# Tabulator.js editing events cellEdited/cellEditing and row.reformat

Tags: tabulator

Typical usage (and my case indeed) is to create Tabulator table with several editable columns and several calculated columns *(with calculations via cell formatters)*

When `cellEdited` occurred after a Tab key used to process to the next cell, I need before to reformat row with new calculations, so calculated columns will show updated results.

But `row.reformat()` removes cells and recreate them in a row, so navigating to the next cell fails with exception, and editing fails.

Perhaps a callback after `cellEdited` and before `cellEditing` is needed *(just before navigating to the next cell, for example)*, so navigating after row.reformat could be done without error

So my question is: how to show reformatted cells of calculated columns just after `cellEdited` ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call the reformat function at any point. in the cell edited callback you should call the ***update*** function on the row component to update any other cells that need to be changed.

I wouldn't recommend using formatters for calculated values because they will have exactly the same issues as you are describing.

You should base them on actual values in your data and use mutators to create the calculated values for these cells. This has the added bonus of making the calculated cells sortable as sorting is carried out on the underlying data not the visual data shown from the formatter.

Checkout the [Mutator Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/mutators) and [Row Componenet Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/components#component-row) for more information